# Clang tooling, check if final or override

Tags: clang, libtooling

Is there a "clang way" to check if `CXXMethodDecl` is specified with `override` or `final` keywords?

I can check it by `std::string::find(" override")` for the string representing `CXXMethodDecl`, but this way looks a little ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that that `final` and `override` are hidden in the attributes of the `clang::Decl`. So the underlying code checks method for `final`.

```
bool FinalReplacer::VisitCXXMethodDecl(CXXMethodDecl *methodDecl) {
    auto pos = find_if(methodDecl->attr_begin(), methodDecl->attr_end(), [](Attr *a) {
        return (a->getKind() == attr::Kind::Final);
    });
    if (pos != methodDecl->attr_end()) {
        //Do something here.
    }
    return true;
}
```

Similarly for `override` attribute is `attr::Kind::Override`.

A complete list of attributes for `clang::Decl` can be found in [clang/Basic/AttrList.inc](https://www.crest.iu.edu/projects/conceptcpp/docs/html-ext/AttrList_8inc_source.html)